# refine((a * E).T * (a * E)) fails

Tags: python, sympy

Following is the `sympy` code that we are having trouble.  We're trying to use simple algebra on an orthogonal matrix.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import a, l

E = MatrixSymbol('E', l, l)
aE = a * E

with assuming(Q.orthogonal(E)):
    print(refine(E.T * E))
    print(refine(aE.T * aE))
```

The first print line completes successfully and gives "I" as we expected.  On the other hand, the print statement at the very end terminates with :

> "AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'T'" error.

The whole error message reads:

```
/Users/wakita/anaconda3/envs/pyqtgl/bin/python "/Users/wakita/Dropbox (smartnova)/work/pysandbox/testsympy/aE.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wakita/Dropbox (smartnova)/work/pysandbox/testsympy/aE.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(refine(aE.T * aE))
  File "/Users/wakita/anaconda3/envs/pyqtgl/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/assumptions/refine.py", line 29, in refine
    args = [refine(arg, assumptions) for arg in expr.args]
  File "/Users/wakita/anaconda3/envs/pyqtgl/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/assumptions/refine.py", line 29, in <listcomp>
    args = [refine(arg, assumptions) for arg in expr.args]
  File "/Users/wakita/anaconda3/envs/pyqtgl/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/assumptions/refine.py", line 29, in refine
    args = [refine(arg, assumptions) for arg in expr.args]
  File "/Users/wakita/anaconda3/envs/pyqtgl/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/assumptions/refine.py", line 29, in <listcomp>
    args = [refine(arg, assumptions) for arg in expr.args]
  File "/Users/wakita/anaconda3/envs/pyqtgl/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/assumptions/refine.py", line 40, in refine
    new_expr = handler(expr, assumptions)
  File "/Users/wakita/anaconda3/envs/pyqtgl/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/matrices/expressions/matmul.py", line 265, in refine_MatMul
    if arg == last.T and ask(Q.orthogonal(arg), assumptions):
AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'T'
```

Comment: You don't define `T`. I assume it's the transposed ?

Comment: It's failing (AFAICT) when it tries to transpose `a`, which is only a generic `Symbol`. I haven't found any way to make `sympy` treat it as a scalar, i.e. to make `.T` a no-op instead of failing.

Comment: I tried Symbol('a', real=True) but it did not work.

Comment: This is definitely a bug in SymPy. I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/11359).

Comment: Thanks I forked the `refine` branch and checked that my problem is resolved.  I hope the branch be merged in the master branch sooner.  Thanks!

https://github.com/parsoyaarihant/sympy/commit/e220dd09448c476bb9af914ab8ba73eda408f587